# Are there any faster alternatives to TemplateControl.ParseControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am rendering ASP.NET markup dynamically by parsing HTML into ASP.NET controls with `TemplateControl.ParseControl` and it works beautifully... the only problem is it can be very slow (our performance tests have shown it can take upwards of several seconds to finish).

Are there any better (*faster*) ways of doing this?

Comment: The logical first question is: why do you need to parse the controls at all? What kind of HTML content are we talking about here? Is it just literal content like divs and spans, or inputs?

Comment: I have a business need to parse ASP.NET HTML markup (the HTML actually contains our own custom .NET controls).  A sample could be the following:

<div>
<asp:Label ID="someLabel" runat="server" text="Label" />
<customControl:myCustomControl ID="customControl" runat="server" CustomProperty="custom" />
</div>

Answer (score 0):

It is said that ParseControl really slower than using the Controls.Add method.
reference: [click here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/30/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-2_2900_.aspx)

Try the controls.add method

```
Dim TextBox1 As New TextBox
TextBox1.Text = "Some Value"
TextBox1.CssClass = "Some Class"

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(TextBox1)
```

Comment: How does this address the issue at all? You need a control before you can add controls. OP has HTML markup that represents a server control, hence the use of the `ParseControl` method.

Comment: I use `TemplateControl.ParseControl` first to generate .NET controls and _then_ I use `Controls.Add` to add the rendered controls.  I need something much faster that can replace the `TemplateControl.ParseControl` call...